# Weird bug when passing data to Laravel notification constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a variable, called `$applicants` and it contains data from users table and other tables from eager load.

Something like this:

[image]

Then I pass that variable to a Laravel Notification class via `__construct` method. The problem is if I `dd` the `$applicant` in the `__construct` method, the data is preserved, but if I `dd` it in the `toMail` method, it only contains data from user table.

[image]

Here is the code:

```php
class DailyReportWasGenerated extends Notification implements ShouldQueue {

    use Queueable;

    private $applicants;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @param $applicants
     */
    public function __construct($applicants)
    {
        $this->applicants = $applicants;

        dd($this->applicants->toArray());
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        dd($this->applicants->toArray());
    }
```

Comment: Could you plz add the class  where you're calling DailyReportWasGenerated ?

Comment: You are probably overriding the constructor of the `Notification` class. In you did so, then you'll have to call the `parent::__construct()` with all its arguments.

Comment: Could you add the code which dispatches/sends the notification?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason here: [Relationship not being passed to notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231030/relationship-not-being-passed-to-notification)

So my solution is just convert my model collection to an array.